# Hoverinfo in an R plotly barchart

Tags: r, plotly, hover, bar-chart

I'm plotting a horizontal bar chart using `R`'s `plotly` package, and including `hoverinfo` parameter:

```
df <- data.frame(n = 17:10, name = paste0("n",1:8), hv_text = paste0("t",1:8), stringsAsFactors = F)
df$name <- factor(df$name, levels = rev(df$name))
library(plotly)
plot_ly(marker = list(line = list(width = 1, color = "gray")), x = df$n, y = df$name, type = 'bar', text = df$hv_text, hoverinfo = "xxx", showlegend = F)
```

Which gives:

[image]

So the `hv_text` gets plotted in addition to appearing when hovered over.

My question is how to get the hoverinfo text not plotted?
I tried using various different values for the `hoverinfo` parameter (`text`,`x`,`y`) but in all cases the `hv_text` gets plotted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this. One way would be to use `hovertext` instead of `text`. For bar charts, if you use `text` without using `hovertext`, it will be plotted.

```
plot_ly(df, marker = list(line = list(width = 1, color = "gray")), 
        x = ~n, y = ~name, type = 'bar', 
        hovertext = ~hv_text, hoverinfo = "text", showlegend = F)
```

[image]

Another option would be to use `hovertext` and `hovertemplate`.

```
plot_ly(df, marker = list(line = list(width = 1, color = "gray")), 
        x = ~n, y = ~name, type = 'bar', hovertext = ~hv_text, 
        hovertemplate = "Name: %{y}<br>Text: %{hovertext}<extra></extra>", 
        showlegend = F)
```

[image]